# How can I hide an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, progressdialog

I have Activity that download a file in progress dialog. And when user press to the button "hide" activity creates notification and hide progress dialog. And when user click to the notification, activity showing progress dialog in the activity again. How could I switch activity to the back task on pressing to the button "Back"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to call `finish()` to remove the `Activity` from the stack.
Then in your notification, you set the name of the `Activity` to be called when you click on it, something like this:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
  "A new notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
// Specify the called Activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityName.class);
intent.putBoolean("isDownloading", true); // check this value in Activity
PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "This is the title",
  "This is the text", activity);
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: No, I don't wanna destroy the Activity beacause it contains all information about progressDialog that I will show again. Did you understand me? So sorry, my English is not good.

Comment: I don't know any way to "hide" the activity unless you call "moveTaskToBack(true)" which will do what the home button does. Anyway, when you click on the notification to open the Activity onCreate() gets called, so therefore it doesn't matter if you "hide it".

Comment: In your case, I would implement a Service and bind it to this Activity, so when you click on the notification, and onCreate() is being called, check for the Intent that is being sent along with the PendingIntent, in order to get a value indicating that a download is in progress. So in your intent you can put something like: intent.putBoolean("isDownloading",true); and then you can do whatever you want depending on this boolean value.

Comment: I made it         <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >

Comment: I mean that my activity is single instance. Thank you very much moveTaskToBack(true) - that is what I'm looked for.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't destroy your activity you must set acitvity launch mode to `single_instance` and use `moveTaskToBack(true)` to send to background.